# eigen3 type cast / copy from pointer (overflow uint8_t)

Tags: c++, eigen3

i get a uint8_t * array (which is fixed defined) and want to use them with a Eigen3 Matrix.

I started using

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<uint8_t, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> Matrix8u;
```

with a `memcpy` to `.data()`

but later i noticed that for example `.sum()` I'm getting an overflow.

Is there a way to make a fast copy between a `uint8_t *` and a int32_t ? - with Eigen::Map ?

Greetings

Comment: I do not know the Eigen datatypes in particular, but usually with containers, you should use the class methods to fill the container with data, or at least, make sure the container has the right size and that memcpy will not break the class invariants.

Comment: What do you mean by "*fast copy between a uint8_t * and a int32_t*"? It doesn't make much sense. @ErikAlapää Eigen uses special alocators, so as you say, it's not safe to use `memcpy` on raw data. But it also provides a proxy facility - `Eigen::Map` which uses plain array as back storage, so you can interface it via `Eigen` API. Still mixing types doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @luk32, i get n * uint8_t from an other api. and need the calculate with these values in an Eigen::Matrix. But if i create the Matrix with the uint8_t type and call .sum() i get an overflow.

Comment: You would need to provide complete example portraying your use-case. Unfortunately `Eigen::sum` returns `Scalar`, so for `uint8_t` matrix it will be... `uint8_t` - easy to overflow. But if you have a pointer to an array and need a sum, why not sum it in a `for` loop skipping `Eigen` altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use Eigen::Map to map your array onto a Matrix8u and then cast it to something like Matrix32i.

Assuming your data is in a form of an array data[] = {0, 1, 2, ...} here is sample code:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<uint8_t, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> Matrix8u;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<int32_t, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> Matrix32i;

uint8_t data[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

Matrix32i m32i = Eigen::Map<Matrix8u>(data, rows, cols).cast<Matrix32i::Scalar>();
```

And of course `rows*cols` must equal the length of your data array.

Comment: This doesn't always work for all libraries.  Do you know how to memcpy onto an eigen row or column?